# Use of window.location doesn't work on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, window.location

I'm using some `JavaScript` that will redirect the user to another `URL` after a fixed period of time. This is working well on all browsers but on an iPad 3 I have to test on it isn't working. The timeout fires and I call

```
window.location = "www.someurl.com";
```

and I've also tried

```
  window.location.href = "www.someurl.com";
```

I can see the `URL` in the browser changing to `www.someurl.ocom` but the browser doesn't actually go there - it stays on the same page.

Is there something iPad specific I have to do to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Does `window.location.assign("foo.html");` make a difference?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try
`location.href = "..."`, should work on both

Comment: Thanks - worked like a charm. Whats significant about window.location that iOS doesn't like?

Answer (score 0):

The right answer here is you are missing the protocol. 
`window.location.href = "http://www.someurl.com";` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

For me changing `https` to `http` made it finally work. Following other answers I also:

- have set the `window.location.href`
- added `return false;` after my change

My redirects worked in every browser and platform i tried **apart of** chrome on ios. After changing the protocol, not the redirects work!

```js
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     window.location.href = "http://bbc.co.uk";
     return false;
  });
```